# How to change the default label "Backorders" in Advanced Inventory?

Tags: magento2, product, forms, inventory, labels

I need to override the default label "Backorders" in Advanced Inventory.

[image]

I've tried to override the label by creating the **product_form.xml** file but nothing happens.

```
<container name="container_backorders">
 <field name="backorders">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Label</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_module/js/form/element/options</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
 </field>
</container>
```

Also I've tried to use Product Form Modifier but I cannot find any Backorders meta.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. I've resolved my problem by adding translation for the word "Backorders" in my Module.